# Check if page allowed comment reply in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As you might know Facebook enabled this "reply on comment" feature recently. And if you have a page, you will find a checkbox in settings saying **Allow replies to comments on my Page.** This means that some pages could have turned this feature off.

So now I have to integrate Graph API requests in my website to post replies. I was wondering if there is a way to get if the page has enabled replies or not. Because if I post reply on a comment which does not support it, I'll get an exception.

To overcome this, I'd like to know a priori if the feature is enabled and do not allow to reply from my site if it is not.

I looked into FB docs, but couldn't find anything. Also there is a "**can_comment**" field in every comment object. Can it be used instead?